# c# asp.net mvc static functions or instantiate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, static, ram

I built a web site and besides the repositories functions which are part of the instance, 
I basically declared all other functions in the site as static. I guess this what I knew from the other place I used to work in. Now I try to make this site production and I noticed the site's IIS process's Ram is accumulating quickly and the site get stuck from the time to time on same functions that are normally quick. Do my static functions can be the cause of that? what are the downsides of this method? any ideas for improvements would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: It entirely depends on what your static functions _do_.

Comment: Try measuring what's using the RAM

Comment: The technical guideline is that when a function can be static it should be static. This should not impact the memory use at all. But it sounds a bit strange to have "all other functions static".

Comment: I guess your methods are not thread safe and some variable is not disposed correctly. But without code, nobody can verify.

Comment: @Nullius how can I check this?